# Rails form select for model with one-to-many relation with itself

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller

I have a `Type` model with one-to-many relation to itself, i.e.

```
class Type < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :supertype, class_name: Type, foreign_key: 'supertype_id'
  has_many :subtypes, class_name: Type, foreign_key: 'supertype_id'
end
```

In form for this model I'd like to have a `<select>` to choose it's supertype from list of existing Types (or nil). What would be correct way to do so? Right now my code looks like so:

```
<%= form_for(@type) do |f| %>
  <%= f.select(:supertype_id, ( Type.all.collect {|t| [ t.name, t.id ] }) + ["",nil] ) %>
<% end %>
```

but obviously that doesn't work.

In my migration I have this code, if that helps:

```
create_table :types do |t|
  t.string :name
  t.references :supertype, index: true, foreign_key: true

  t.timestamps null: false
end
```

Comment: For a top-level `Type`. I really don't think that nil is the issue here though, this code doesn't generate correct model even if I choose legit `Type` from list.

Comment: Can you be more specific about why it doesn't work? Is the controller giving some kind of error? Are the values POSTing as expected? If you attempt to assign `supertype_id` directly in the console, does that work?

Comment: Are your type names unique in your `types` table? If not, you might want to consider a separate table, say, `type_names` that assigns unique id's to unique names, then use that table as your source for the selector.

Comment: This code produces `undefined method 'arel_table' for ActiveRecord::Type:Module` when I try to access supertype like in `<p><%= @type.supertype.name %></p>` and setting `supertype_id` in console doesn't help. And form data looks like `type[name]:typename
type[supertype_id]:2
commit:Create Type`, so I'd *guess* it's ok.

Comment: @lurker Yes, they are supposed to be unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `belongs_to` and `has_many` calls need to specify `:class_name` as a *String* not as the actual class object (and you can optionally omit the `:foreign_key` on the `belongs_to`):

```
class Type < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :supertype, class_name: "Type"
  has_many :subtypes, class_name: "Type", foreign_key: 'supertype_id'
end
```

Comment: Thanks, that was it :)